# How can I show an Assets image within my Low Search Results?

Tags: assets, low-search

How can I show an Assets image within my Low Search Results?

Ive tried the variable name and using the pair {my_assets_field var_prefix="file:}{file:url}{/my_assets_field}

Comment: Well, the code you typed here is invalid... Have you tried making that colon a double quote? Also have you tried without the prefix? The search result tag functions just like a channel entries tag.

Comment: Apologies for the typo but yes Ive tried with and without the prefix